# Метод средних прямоугольников с адаптированной сеткой

Tags: математика

Необходимо исследовать сходимость метода средних прямоугольников с адаптированной сеткой. Вопрос вот в чем: в результате получилось, что сходимость метода не стремится к какому-либо числу а "флуктуирует", если можно так сказать, рядом с нулем (а иногда и не рядом). Это ошибка у меня? или так и должно быть? Если так и должно быть, то с чем это связано? Гуглила везде, не нашла ничего.
Функция которую интегрирую: exp(-x) в интервале [0,20]. Полученные значения скорости сходимости:

```
Steps of grid: 2 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -1.07
Steps of grid: 4 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -2.92
Steps of grid: 8 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -1.14
Steps of grid: 16 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.64
Steps of grid: 32 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -1.8
Steps of grid: 64 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.21
Steps of grid: 128 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.37
Steps of grid: 256 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.1
Steps of grid: 512 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.02
Steps of grid: 1024 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -3.94
Steps of grid: 2048 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.62
Steps of grid: 4096 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -1.5
Steps of grid: 8192 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.16
Steps of grid: 16384 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.25
Steps of grid: 32768 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.06
Steps of grid: 65536 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.03
Steps of grid: 131072 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.01
Steps of grid: 262144 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -0.0
Steps of grid: 524288 Convergence speed of adapt grid method: -5.45
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А как определяется скорость сходимости?

Comment: Как log(погрешность[i]/погрешность[i-1])/log(шаг сетки[i]/шаг сетки[i-1]). Вот сейчас написала это и подумала, ведь в этой то формуле получается что не учитывается что разбиение сетки неравномерно, наверно в этом ошибка. Но, если пытаться учитывать неравномерность разбиение сетки, получится как-то больно сложно. Вероятно есть более элегантный способ решения этой проблемы.